# How to change ProgressBar visibility in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

```
ProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectingString"].ConnectionString);

try
{

    await con.OpenAsync();
    ProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    MainWindow X= new MainWindow();
    X.Show();
    this.Close();
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    MessageBox.Show("Connection failed");
}
```

The code above represents a command for a button I have (MVVM). However, I'm not sure how I could make a property for it (ProgressBar) in ViewModel and still call it in the button code as in the order given above.

Comment: Give your viewmodel a boolean property with an appropriate name. `HasConnection` or something like that. Make sure it raises `PropertyChanged` when its value changes. Using [`BoolToVisibilityConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), bind that to the progressbar's `Visibility` property in the XAML: `Visibility="{Binding HasConnection, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"`.

Comment: If any of your code throws exception, you will never close the `con`. It would be better to wrap it in `using()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all I really recommend working with MVVM framework like prism or MVVM light because they offer a lot of features like notify the UI or commands implementation like delegate command, moving on to your question, first of all you should move your business logic into your View model or another tier (if you are using n-tier architecture), so your view model should look something like this:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool displayProgress;

    public bool DisplayProgress
    {
        get { return displayProgress; }
        set
        {
            displayProgress = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public async Task<List<string>> LoadData()
    {
        DisplayProgress = true;
        //Here connect to the database and graph your data
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);//to demonstrate the delay
        });
        DisplayProgress = false;
        return new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };

    }
}
```

As you can see, the view model implements INotifyPropertyChanged in order to notify the view when a bonded property changed like the display progress bar which we are going to bind to visibility property inside our progress bar and use BooleanToVisibilityConverter as following:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    xmlns:windowsControl="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=PresentationFramework"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <windowsControl:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisibilityConverter"></windowsControl:BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ProgressBar  IsIndeterminate="True" Height="50" Margin="5" Visibility="{Binding Path=DisplayProgress, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter }}"></ProgressBar>
    <Button Name="loadButton" Grid.Row="1" Width="80" Height="40" Click="loadButton_Click">Load Data</Button>
</Grid>
```

As you can see I have used the build in converter "BooleanToVisibilityConverter" inside "System.Windows.Controls" namespace (don't forget to implement it) and then bind the progressbar visibility as following:

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=DisplayProgress, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter }}"
```

finally my MainWindow code behind is

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MainWindowViewModel viewModel;

    public MainWindowViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return viewModel; }
        set
        {
            viewModel = value;
            DataContext = viewModel;
        }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }

    private async void loadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = await ViewModel.LoadData();
        //display the data on the UI (only testing code)
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        data.ForEach(item => result.Append($"{item},"));
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
    }
}
```